# How to optimize my lighting shader?

Tags: shaders, glsl, lighting, cocos2d-x

I want to create a lighting effect on a gray-scaled world using cocos2d-x. What I've done is creating a layer which runs a shader program that receives light positions and radiuses as input and greyscales every pixel that doesn't fall in a light area. The lights are standard CCSprites which are children of my custom layer and are blended with the background.

The problem is that my fragment shader code is very slow on iPad where the frame rate drops to 15 fps.

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec2      v_texCoord;
varying vec4      v_v2Position;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec2      u_v2LightPositions[8];
uniform int       u_iLightStatus[8];
uniform float     u_fRadiusSquared[8];


void main()
{ 
  vec4 currentTexelColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);

  float gray = dot(currentTexelColor.rgb, vec3( 0.299, 0.587, 0.114 ) );

  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
      float fDistance_x = v_v2Position.x - u_v2LightPositions[i].x;
      float fDistance_y = v_v2Position.y - u_v2LightPositions[i].y;
      if( ( u_iLightStatus[i] == 1 ) 
       && ( ( (fDistance_x * fDistance_x ) + ( fDistance_y * fDistance_y ) ) <  u_fRadiusSquared[i] ) )
      {
          gl_FragColor = currentTexelColor;
          return;
      }     
  }

  gl_FragColor = vec4( gray, gray, gray, currentTexelColor.a );

}
```

Is there any way to optimize this shader? I tried unrolling the loop by writing calculations for each light by hand but I didn't get any better results.

Comment: what about eliminating the if clause? replacing it with an step function?

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your float variables outside of the loop. It doesn't make sense to declare them in each run of the loop. Let me know, how many frames you could gain.